# Dynamic date in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql

I am working on a question where I want to have a dynamic filter for date(I want to see the last 6 months based on today's date). Orderdate is INT which is why I am using nvarchar and then date. When I use the code below I get the following error message "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.". Does anyone know what I can do to fix this?

```
cast(cast(OrderDate as nvarchar) as date) > dateadd(month,-6, getdate())
```

Comment: Edit your question and show examples of `OrderDate`.  Why would a column whose name includes "date" be stored as a string?

Comment: "Orderdate is INT". There's your problem right there. Use `Date` to specify a date, or `DateTime2` to specify a date and time.

Comment: Why is orderdate an int? Obviously you've stored some integer value that isn't actually a date. It could be `20180231` or it could be `436289`. This is what you get when you use the wrong data type. Also, [don't ever specify `nvarchar` etc. without length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Ha, I was just thinking I should link to your [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)...

Comment: You might have stored values in incorrect way , it should be `yearmonthdate` as `int` or it should not return that above mentioned error

Comment: @BHouse: "You might have stored values in incorrect way" too soft. the OP most definitely stores values in an incorrect way. dates should not be stored as integers.

Comment: @ZoharPeled guess OP has disappeared from rador

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution is to use `try_convert()`.

```
try_convert(date, try_convert(varchar(255), OrderDate))  > dateadd(month, -6, getdate())
```

That will remove the error, but probably does not fix the underlying problem.

You can find the offending values by doing:

```
select OrderDate
from t
where OrderDate is not null and
      try_convert(date, try_convert(varchar(255), OrderDate)) is null
```